# How to determine if certain combinations of rows exist in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I want to be able to return a list of unique Ids in a child table that do not contain certain rows.

My table looks similar to:

```
Id  Name
1   X
1   Y
1   Z
2   A
2   B
2   C
3   X
3   B
3   Z
```

I want to write a SQL query like

```
SELECT Id
FROM table t
WHERE UPPER(t.Name) IN ('X', 'Y', 'Z') 
      OR UPPER(t.Name) IN ('A', 'B', 'C')  
GROUP BY t.Id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT UPPER(t.Name)) != 3
```

But this does not work, as I would expect only Id = 3 to be returned as invalid.

Is this possible in a single SQL statement?

Also, is it possible to solve this problem if there are an arbitrary number of lists (X,Y,Z; A,B,C; P,Q,Z; ...) or a mixed list lengths (X,Y; A,B,C,D; L,M,N; ...)?

> EDIT:

To clarify, each id is really referring to a parent table.  So these are child records.

In first example, the parent record is only valid if it contains at least 3 children.  The 3 children must be named (A, B, and C) or (X, Y, and Z).  A parent is valid even if it contains all 6 children.  But having 4 children named A, B, X, Y would not be valid (adding a C or Z child would make it valid).

So far, Gordon Linoff is closest.  I need to write some more tests.

Of course this is a contrived example, in my implementation different rule sets will require me to use different sets of lists of different sizes (potentially mixed).  For example, I may have a rule where the parent is valid only if it has children named (A and B) or (W, X, Y, and Z) or (L, M, N and Z).

Thanks,

Comment: What RDBMS (Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, ...) are you using?

Comment: All of your IDs have 3 distinct names, your having clause is going to strip everything out.

Comment: I need to support both SQL Server and Oracle.

Comment: So you need those IDs that have at *least one* matching element for each group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find all rows that do not contain X, Y, Z or A, B, C.  You can do this with aggregation and a having clause:

```
select id
from t
group by name
having not ((sum(case when Name = 'X' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
             sum(case when Name = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
             sum(case when Name = 'Z' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
            ) or
            (sum(case when Name = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
             sum(case when Name = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
             sum(case when Name = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
            )
       );
```

Each condition in the `having` clause counts the number of rows that match a particular name.  A row passes the filter when there is at least one.  The combination of `and` and `or` seems to meet your requirement.

Note that an `id` that has A, B, C, and D will match.  Your question doesn't specify whether this is correct or incorrect.

Comment: A,B,C, D would be valid if checking for A,B,C.

Comment: The only change I made to help with dynamically creating this statement was to use a structure like (SUM(CASE WHEN UPPER(c.Name) IN ('X', 'Y', 'Z') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 3) to replace the individual calls.

Comment: @SergioL . . . That is fine, if you know that there are no duplicate values on the rows.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e708c/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl ( Id NUMBER(1),  Name VARCHAR2(1) );

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ( 1,   'X' );
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ( 1,   'Y' );
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ( 1,   'Z' );
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ( 2,   'A' );
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ( 2,   'B' );
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ( 2,   'C' );
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ( 3,   'X' );
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ( 3,   'B' );
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ( 3,   'Z' );
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ( 4,   'F' );
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ( 4,   'G' );
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ( 4,   'H' );

CREATE TYPE VARCHAR2s_1_Table AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1);
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH groups AS (
  SELECT id,
         CAST( COLLECT( Name ) AS VARCHAR2s_1_Table ) AS grp
  FROM   tbl
  GROUP BY
         id
)
SELECT id
FROM   groups
WHERE  ( grp MULTISET INTERSECT VARCHAR2s_1_Table( 'X', 'Y', 'Z') ) IS NOT EMPTY
AND    ( grp MULTISET INTERSECT VARCHAR2s_1_Table( 'A', 'B', 'C') ) IS NOT EMPTY
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e708c/1/0)**:

```
| ID |
|----|
|  3 |
```

Comment: `WHERE VARCHAR2s_1_Table( 'X', 'Y', 'Z') IS NOT SUBMULTISET OF grp` would work as well, I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TYPE string_table
AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1);

WITH grouped_names AS (
   SELECT
      id,
      CAST(COLLECT(name) AS string_table) AS names_grp
   FROM tbl
   GROUP BY id
)
SELECT id
FROM grouped_names
WHERE string_table('A','B','C') NOT SUBMULTISET OF names_grp
  AND string_table('X','Y','Z') NOT SUBMULTISET OF names_grp
```